# Write $−6\sin x−8\cos x$ in the form $K\sin(x+\alpha)$

Tags: trigonometry

I am having trouble finding $\alpha$ in this problem. The full question:

```
Write the given expression in the form ksin(x+α) for 0≤α≤2π. Round α to 3 decimal places. 

−6sinx−8cosx
```

I understand that $k=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

So I get $\cos x=-8/10$ and $\sin x=-6/10$

The only two reasonable answers of the bunch are as follows:

```
10sin(x+4.652)
 -or-
10sin(x+4.069)
```

My results are:

$10\sin(x+\arctan(3/4))$

I'm unsure of how they got $4.652$ or $4.069$ as answers or either of them could be correct considering $\arctan(3/4)$ or just $\tan(3/4)$ is not either of them from my findings, where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Your minus sign disappeared, so you probably have to add or subtract some multiple of $\pi$ or subtract from multiple of $\pi$.  You might need $4/3$ rather than $3/4$.  I think you have sin and cos reversed.

Comment: You are using $ \ A \sin(x + \alpha) \  = A (\sin x \cos \alpha + \cos x \sin \alpha) \ \ , $ so that should be $ \ \cos \alpha \ = \ -6/10 \ $ and $ \  \sin \alpha \ = \ -8/10 \ \ , \ $  making $ \ \tan \alpha \ = \ 4/3 \ \ . $  You now have $  \ -10 \sin (x \ + \ \arctan(4/3) ) \ \ , $ so the answer is adding $ \ \pi \ $ to the phase-angle in order to have $ \ A \ = \ +10 \ \ . $  I'm getting that $ \ 4.069 \ $ is the correct phase-angle.

Comment: The question doesn't say $k\ge 0$, so another possible answer would be $$10\sin(x+4.069) = -10\sin(x+4.069-\pi) = \boxed{-10\sin(x+0.927)}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y=10\left(-\frac{6}{10}\sin(x)-\frac{8}{10}\cos(x)  \right)$$
Let $\cos(\theta)=-\frac{6}{10}$ and $\sin(\theta)=-\frac{8}{10}$, so the angle $\theta$ is in the 3rd quadrant, $\theta\in [\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}]$

$$\theta=\pi+\arctan\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)=4.069...$$

$$y=10(\cos(\theta)\sin(x)+\sin(\theta)\cos(x))=10\sin(x+\theta)$$